# 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux

```js
import {LOADING_POSTS, GET_ERROR, UPDATE_POSTS} from './postTypes';

const initialState = {
    loading : false,
    posts : [],
    error : ''
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOADING_POSTS :
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : true
            };
        case UPDATE_POSTS : 
            return {
                loading : false,
                posts : state.posts.concat(action.data),
                error : ''
            };
        case GET_ERROR : 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : false,
                error : action.error
            };
        default : return state;
    }
}

export default postReducer;
```

Whenever I try to update the posts I get 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined'. Any Idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you looked at [any of the other questions about this same error (Cannot read property '' of undefined) on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+read+property+%27%27+of+undefined)? You can [limit to just those about redux if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+read+property+%27%27+of+undefined+%5Bredux%5D)...

Comment: yes I did, nothing came out...

Comment: Check out when you call postReducer function, if you want to use the initial state (because you has default values), you should call it: postReducer(undefined, action), or better put your optional parameters at the end of function.

Comment: Can you try: removing `= initialState` from the parameter list and put this at the top of your function before your switch -> `if (typeof state === 'undefined') {return initialState}`

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I tried what you proposed and I got an error saying that initialState is not defined, which explains why state.posts is undefined too

Comment: @houssamghannoum then if that is the case, try exporting both of those `const`'s. Or even, just put this in your parameter list `state = {loading : false, posts : [], error : ''}`, can't be undefined if it's not a variable. If that second option doesn't work, something else is afoot.

Comment: seems like the problem is within the parameters because even this way it remains undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `state.posts` is not set at the time you try to `concat` new data to it.

You can throw a check in there to prevent the errors (if this just gets called before `posts` is  set). If `posts` does not get set at all, investigate why it is not getting passed through.

```
return {
  loading : false,
  posts : (state.posts 
    && Array.isArray(state.posts) // Extra check, you do not need this one if you are certain of the type
    && state.posts.concat(action.data)),
  error : ''
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why would be `undefined` if in the `initialState` he's already setting as `posts : []`?

Comment: @pmiranda Couple different possible reasons why: 1) There's the possibility that OP may be modifying the data outside of the scope of the post. 2) OP may not be using ES6 currently, and I dont think the `default arguments` work non ES6 (based of the docs > https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/). All I know is that that `posts` does not exist at that point.

Comment: I tried this but the condition is always being false which is returning undefined

Comment: @houssamghannoum what is the value of `state` within the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it actually worked!

```js
import {LOADING_POSTS, GET_ERROR, UPDATE_POSTS} from './postTypes';

const initialState = {
    loading : false,
    posts : [],
    error : ''
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOADING_POSTS :
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : true
            };
        case UPDATE_POSTS : 
            return {
                loading: false,
                posts: state.posts ? state.posts.concat(action.data) : action.data,
                error : ''
            };
        case GET_ERROR : 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : false,
                error : action.error
            };
        default : return state;
    }
}

export default postReducer;
```